# How can I create a model *other-than-human* for pose detection in video?

Tags: google-mlkit

For example, let's say I want to track and identify activity by a motocross rider.  I want to do the same thing that pose detection does, but I want to do it for an object that is NOT human (it may be a combination of a human and another object, like a motocross bike, but not only a human.)  So the question is, how do I create a model similar to the pose-detection model, but with whatever landmarks I decide to include in the model, so that I can cover the person plus the object they're connected to.  I want to create a completely new model.  I don't want to add to the human model.  Thanks for your help.

I have not begun working on this yet.